# Gridlines too long

Tags: plotting

When I produce a simple plot like so:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic,  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red]]
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the grid lines cross over the vertical axis on the left, going all the way through the first character of the tick labels. I see this regardless of StyleSheet used. Looks like a bug to me, but perhaps there's a way to fix this? Of course, ideally I'd also have the tick labels on the horizontal axis printed on top of the grid lines rather than the other way around, but that may be to reasonable a choice to ask for...

**Edit:**

Never mind the question on the too long gridlines; I found the answer (use `PlotRangePadding -> 0`). My question on having the gridlines in the background remains, however.

Comment: `TicksStyle -> Directive[Background -> Directive[Opacity[0.75], White]]` increases the contrast between the tick labels and the grid lines.

Comment: @Michael E2: By the way, this is an excellent suggestion, which does pretty much exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The grid-lines are directly connected to the `PlotRange` that you use. Although you only plot from 0 to `2*Pi`, *Mathematica* adds a little space around your plot. This little space, called `PlotRangePadding` is the source of this issue:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red], 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As for your other question

> Of course, ideally I'd also have the tick labels on the horizontal axis printed on top of the grid lines rather than the other way around

Well, at least for me it seems that grid is indeed in the background which can be shown in a magnified screenshot. Of course, red grid-lines in combination with gray axes aren't the best design choice:

[image]

As a final note, if you could live for instance with gray grid-lines, the complete issue doesn't look so bad after all. Even if you extend your plot further to the left:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer while you were typing yours ;-)

Comment: P.S.: Still looks like a bug to me, or just the typical Wolfram sloppiness. It makes no sense whatsoever to have these grid lines extend beyond the axes and clash with the tick labels. By the way, is there a reason for the default non-zero setting of PlotRangePadding? What is it that this default helps with? Heck, why would I even be interested in having such an option available?

Comment: Usually it is a good thing to have some extra-space. Even in your example above, you can see that the curve is cropped on bottom and top, but a more obvious example would be `ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], PlotRangePadding -> 0]`, where points are cut into half. So instead of always adjusting the plot-range, *Mathematica* adds a little space to make all of the function visible.

Comment: P.P.S.: I looked at Wolfram's documentation for PlotRangePadding, and now the grid lines issue makes even less sense. From the examples given I see absolutely no reason for this behavior, noting, however, that all examples use `Frame->True`.

Comment: The issue with clipped curves can be solved by `PlotRangeClipping->False`, or by setting the PlotRange explicitly. I still cannot see any reason for having the grid lines behave the way they do. It's a bug in my book.

Comment: No, `PlotRangeClipping` is only the solution, if you have set an `ImagePadding` greater than zero. As soon as `ImagePadding` is zero or your plot-style of functions or points are larger than what you have for `ImagePadding`, the plot is clipped too.

Comment: @Pirx In my mind the axes are *inside* the graphics field (whereas a frame lies *around* it).  Naturally the grid lines will extend past the axes or any other graphics element to the edges of the field unless the elements happen to coincide with the edge of the field.

Comment: @Pirx What about that "axes thicks are not on top of the grid" part of your question? See my updated answer. The only real dilemma you have is that in a plot like yours you want the axis to cross at {0,0} which makes the extension of the grid to the left look weird.

Comment: @halirutan: I now see that you're right, the labels do seem on top of the lines. I only chose the red color for demonstration purposes, in most cases gray lines will be fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael E2: I understand that there is a way to formally justify the behavior of those grid lines. However, in just about any practical application (and in all analogous software packages), the gridlines are there for a specific purpose, and we want them to end at the axis line when the plot is bounded by the axis.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a `Frame` cleans it up nicely:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

A little more `Frame` work gives the appearance of a non-framed plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red], AxesStyle -> Opacity[0],
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Another option, but with the x-axis at y=0:

```
ct = Table[{i, Row[{"   ", i}]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 1}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red], Ticks -> {ct, Automatic}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {0, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks, but what if I don't want a frame?

Comment: @Pirx I updated with some more frame settings

Comment: Nice, but I'm not so easy to satisfy: I really may want that x-axis with its labels and ticks shown at y=0. Sorry ;-)

Comment: @Pirx updated ... I'm stubborn =)

Comment: That's a solution, yes. In this case I', drawing my axis manually. There's really nothing to quibble about your approach. However, I  would expect Mathematica to give me such reasonable behavior by default, not me having to write the code for it myself.